# Using control.setDisabled() after promise

Tags: javascript, promise, dynamics-crm, es6-promise, dynamics-365

I'm writing some JS for Dynamics 365 which disables (locks) the fields on the selected editable subgrid row.

The method to do this is `.setDisabled()` ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/setdisabled)). I can run the following method which will lock all the fields upon selecting a row:

```
function onGridRowSelected(context){
    context.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attr) {
        attr.controls.forEach(function (myField) {
            myField.setDisabled(foundResponse);
        })
    });
}
```

The issue I am having is trying to run the above following a promise. I have the following code which will pass the result of a promise into my disable fields methods:

```
var gridContext;
function onGridRowSelected(context){
    gridContext = context.getFormContext();

    //Retrieve the record we want to check the value on
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("ms_approvalquery", "?$select=ms_responsetext&$top=1&$orderby=createdon desc")
    .then(result => disableOrEnableFields(result));
}


function disableOrEnableFields(result){
    //Check if the record found has a ms_responsetext != null
    var foundResponse = false
    if (result.entities[0].ms_responsetext != null){
        foundResponse = true;
    }

    //Either disable/enable all the row columns depending on the value retrieved from the above
    gridContext.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attr) {
        attr.controls.forEach(function (myField) {
            myField.setDisabled(foundResponse);
        })
    });
}
```

When stepping through debug, I can see that `myField.setDisabled(true);` is getting called but nothing is happening. Is this because it's on a separate thread? How do I get back to the main thread with the result of my promise?

Note: Using Async/Await doesn't work either - it gives the same results.

Comment: we had similar issues few days back, unfortunately Async/Await/promise call does not respect grid control, you will have to go by old/classic Sync call way and then it shall work. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Ahh thought I was going mad! I'll use xmlHttpRequest instead. Thanks @AnkUser :)

Comment: I will add my above comment as answer :) will give me some points if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had similar issues few days back, unfortunately Async/Await/promise call does not respect grid control, you will have to go by old/classic Sync call way and then it shall work. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I used XMLHttpRequest() to fetch my data synchronously, this let me work with the subgrid correctly. Thanks for the help :)